# Can cycloalkanes undergo electrophilic addition? If so, what is their mechanism?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Cycloalkanes have the same general formula as alkenes. Doesn't this mean that cycloalkanes can be saturated by turning into alkanes the same way alkenes use? If so, what is the reaction mechanism? In the reaction mechanism of the electrophilic addition of alkenes, a pair of electrons are taken from a C-C double bond and donated to one atom of the attacking binary compound. In the reaction mechanism of the electrophilic addition of cycloalkanes will one entire single bond be broken and the pair of electrons in it donated to one atom of the attacking binary compound? This way it is possible to produce an alkane from a cycloalkane undergoing electrophilic addition, but in terms of energy requirements, I find it a bit unlikely. I think it would be useful if someone could help me clarify this.

Comment: You are generalising on a far too high level, and have lost ground. ;) Take cyclohexane and bromine. Do they react?

Comment: Pretty much only cyclopropane reacts somewhat similarly to alkenes.

Comment: Then why don't cyclohexane and bromine react? Because of energy requirements?